Adding error bars in ggplot and organizing data with plyr
I want to plot mean daily duration for 3 sites using line/dot plot with SD error bars
y=duration x=day
I am struggling to add error bars to my line/dot plot. When i enter the code it is not recognizing my callouts for x and y
This is the code I am using for plot:
dailywater <- ddply(DailyWaterMeans, c("site", "day"), summarise, duration=mean(duration))
dailyplot2 <- ggplot(dailywater, aes(x=day, y=duration)) +geom_line(aes(group=site)) +geom_point(aes(fill=site)) 
  xlab("Days Post Weaning") + ylab("Mean Duration in Water (minutes)") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="NA")) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", linewidth = .5, linetype = 1)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14)) + xlim(23,38) 

when I add geom_errorbar I get errors. I know something is wrong with how I am organizing in ddply, but I am new to this and can't figure it out with books or googling
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = duration-sd, ymax = duration + sd), width=.2)


It doesn't look like you calculate your sd variable at any point. You may need to add sd = sd(duration) to your ddplyr statement. It would be helpful if you are able to provide some of your data and code in the form of a reproducible example
